# Interleave Bytearray of Shorts

Tags: python, arrays, struct

I have two bytearrays of an equal length determined at runtime. The data in the bytearrays are unsigned shorts (16-bit values):

`bytearray1 = [u1, u2, ..., un]`

`bytearray2 = [v1, v2, ..., vn]`

where the u's and the v's are 16-bit values.

How can I interleave these arrays into a new array that looks like this:

`bytearray3 = [u1, v1, u2, v2, ..., un, vn]`

I think it should be possible using the `struct` functions (perhaps a combination of `struct.unpack` and `struct.pack_into` in a `for` loop), but I can't quite see how to do it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `bytearray3 = bytearray(itertools.chain(*zip(bytearray1, bytearray2)))`

Comment: Thank you.  This gives the correct result.